# Почему отсутствует второе тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Предложение взято отсюда:

https://www.google.ru/url?q=http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer%3Fs%3D%25D0%25B2%2520%25D0%25BA%25D0%25BE%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D1%258B%25D0%25B9%2520%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B7&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwivqIvv6JTZAhULGuwKHcAbD0cQFjAAegQIDxAB&usg=AOvVaw3gEUUL-g1zmICMeeIeM7Y8

> Уставный капитал акционерных обществ разделен на акции, которые принадлежат участникам акционерных обществ — акционерам и удостоверяют обязательственные права акционеров.

Акционерам - приложение, в данном случае выделяющееся тире. Почему пропущено еще одно тире  перед и?

Comment: Видимо, "акционер" здесь входит в понятие "участник-акционер", в отличие от других категорий участников АО.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае в тексте попутно дается определение: **участник акционерных обществ  — акционер.**

В правилах Розенталя этот вариант можно отнести к следующей теме: **общее значение определяемого слова и конкретное значение приложения.**

Также здесь **не применяется вставочная интонация с двумя паузами**, которая соответствовала бы двум тире.

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Примечание. **Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:**

2) если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение: **Высшая награда** Французского института океанографии за выдающиеся океанографические работы — **медаль в память** Альберта I принца Монакского присуждена видному учёному Л. А. Зенькевичу (Газ.);

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Тоже хотел оставить одно тире, но не смог найти таких хороших аргументов.

Answer (score 0):

В [ответе](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=277119), данном "Справочной службой русского языка",  верно сказано, что пунктуация зависимости от смысла, вложенного автором текста. А так как сам автор не уверен в правильности постановки знаков препинания, мы можем только гадать, какой смысл автор хотел вложить.

Мое предположение таково. Автор хочет сказать, что *участник акционерного  общества* и *акционер* — суть одно и то же. Это подтверждается тем, что далее в предложении термин "акционер" употреблен еще один раз, а также тем определением, которое я нашел в Сети:

> Участники АО называются акционерами. (https://www.egrul.ru/articles/30.html)

А раз так, то нужно следовать рекоммендации Справочной службы для этого случая и употребить скобки:

**Уставный капитал акционерных обществ разделен на акции, которые принадлежат участникам акционерных обществ (акционерам) и удостоверяют обязательственные права акционеров.**

На мой взгляд, два тире могут послужить альтернативой скобкам:

**Уставный капитал акционерных обществ разделен на акции, которые принадлежат участникам акционерных обществ — акционерам — и удостоверяют обязательственные права акционеров.**

Comment: Если в тексте впервые упоминаются акционеры, то  вставочная (добавочная, пояснительная) конструкция не подходит. А Справочная служба дает только рекомендации, то есть своё толкование законов правописания,  а сами законы  изложены в двух  известных документах. Вот пусть и дают ссылки на них.